# ClearInterval() is not working properly in the following code logic

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My simple logic is, i have a j-query popup to be opened after every certain time(To ask user that his/her session time is going to expire within 60 seconds). And there are 2 buttons on that pop-up to **continue**, if user clicks on continue an ajax request increases its session time for certain time, or user can choose **logout** button or user will be redirected to logout after 60 seconds automatically by an ajax automated call.

**The problem is-:** On that pop there is a timer of 60 seconds, when i click on **Continue** button the pop goes off and and pops up again after the time setted in `setInterval` method but the timer starts with second count of where its has been clicked on previous count(suppose, it was clicked on 47 seconds, its should start on 60, but it starts from 47), i could not where i am lacking. here is the my code

```
var timeExpire=60000; // a global variable for pop up
            var interval="";
            var counter=60;

          setInterval(function () {  // This setInterval opens up the pop after every 60 seconds.
                $("#dialog").dialog({    //dialog to be opened
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: "Session Dialog",
                    width: 300,
                    height: 250,
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    open: function(event, ui) { //just to hide the close button from popup
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                          }
                      });
                      if($('#dialog').dialog('open')){
                           interval = setInterval(function() { //another setInterval to start the timer on pop up,
                            counter--;
                            if(counter < 0) {
                                clearInterval(interval);      //Clear the interval.
                                $('#dialog').dialog('close'); //unload Popup Box.
                            } else {
                                $("span#timer").text(counter.toString());  //Show timer of 60 seconds on PopUp Box.
                            }
                         }, 1000);
                      }
                  }, 30000);
```

And Here is the ajax code by which i am updating the session, and i have called the `clearInterval(interval)` function here to clear the `setInterval` (used for timer on popup). 
**Ajax Code:**

```
function loginagain(){
       clearInterval(interval); // Wants to clear the time interval and popup timer should start with the start. 
        $.ajax({
            url:'loginagain.php',
            type:'post',
            success:function(response){
                if((response.length)>1){ 
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    timeExpire=response;
                      }
                  }
             });
        }
```

Guys i know here could be many mistakes in this question, i just request please, suggest for better, and resolve my issue. 
Appreciation in advance.

Here is the pop `html` code

```
<!--Open a dialog after every 10 minutes asking agent to login again..(starts here)-->
<div id="dialog" style="display: none" align = "center">

    <span id="timer"></span>
   Your session is going to expire within 60 seconds. If you want to continue click on <button id="loginAgain" class="btn btn-default" onclick="loginagain();" >Continue</button>
   <br><br> or<br><br> If you want to logged Out click on <a class="btn btn-default" href="logout.php">logout</a>
</div>
<!--Ends here-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to reset your counter value too after calling clearInterval

```
clearInterval(interval);
counter=60;
```

Comment: Hey @Santosh, Thank you so much, its kinda working now, but a tiny problem. When it pops up again, timer first shows the last second on which it has been clicked on and then starts with the time i want.

Comment: You can set `$("span#timer").text('60')` OR `$("span#timer").text('')`after counter reset.

Comment: Hey @SanthoshNayak, it worked like charm,, thanks again,,

Comment: You can give your thanks by accepting this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

**@SanthoshNayak's answer is correct. I would not accept my "answer" over his, i'm just adding this here because I think it's helpful**

IMO by utilizing the events that come with JQuery UI's dialog you make this code a little easier to follow and debug.

```
var timeExpire=60000; // a global variable for pop up
var interval; // interval to time the dialog


var spanInterval; // interval to update text in dialog
var $dialog = $("#dialog"); // cache dialog selector
var $timerSpan = $("#timer"); // cache timer selector

var counter = 60;


// initialize dialog with options 

$dialog.dialog({    //dialog to be opened
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Session Dialog",
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) { 
      // hide close button      
      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
      //set correct time in dialog
      $timerSpan.text(counter.toString());
      // start the function that takes care of updating dialog counter
      spanInterval = setInterval(updateDialogTime, 1000);  
    },
    close: function(event,ui){
       // stop the function that takes care of updating dialog counter
        clearInterval(spanInterval);
      // reset the counter time 
        counter = 60; 
    }
  });    

// takes care of updating dialog span text
function updateDialogTime(){
    if($dialog.dialog('isOpen')) {
      counter--;
      $timerSpan.text(counter.toString());

      if(counter < 0) {        
        $dialog.dialog('close'); //unload Popup Box.
      } 
  }  
}

// wrap dialog open call in function so setInterval can use it 
function showDialog(){
  $dialog.dialog('open');
}

// show after 5 seconds for testing
interval = setInterval(showDialog, 3000);



function loginagain(){
 clearInterval(interval);    

  // fake an ajax response response for testing
  // remove in production code  
  $('#dialog').dialog('close');
  // reopen in 10 seconds to ensure (for testing)  
  timeExpire=10000;
  interval = setInterval(showDialog, timeExpire);  

/*  
        $.ajax({
            url:'loginagain.php',
            type:'post',
            success:function(response){
                if((response.length)>1){ 
                    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    timeExpire=response;
                   interval = setInterval(showDialog, timeExpire);
                      }

              }
         });
*/
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it is helpfull for sure.. @bassxzero